# Missing api key android Cloudinary upload error

Tags: android, cloudinary

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="CLOUDINARY_URL"
        android:value="${cloudinaryUrl}" />
```

In my activity that uploads the file I have init the MediaManager

```
MediaManager.init(this);
```

And I have uploaded the file using its uri by this:

```
val requestId = MediaManager.get().upload(uri).callback(object : UploadCallback {
    override fun onStart(requestId: String) {
        // your code here
    }

    override fun onProgress(requestId: String, bytes: Long, totalBytes: Long) {
        // example code starts here
        val progress = bytes.toDouble() / totalBytes
        // post progress to app UI (e.g. progress bar, notification)
        // example code ends here
    }

    override fun onSuccess(requestId: String, resultData: Map<*, *>) {
        // your code here
    }

    override fun onError(requestId: String, error: ErrorInfo) {
        // your code here
    }

    override fun onReschedule(requestId: String, error: ErrorInfo) {
        // your code here
    }
}).dispatch()
```

The problem is that I am getting an error `'Missing api key'`. Do I need an api key for unsigned uploads?

Comment: Yes you need CLOUDINARY_URL for your implementation

Comment: @sohel.eco I have added the CLOUDINARY_URL to the manifest meta-data. The error says about missing api_key.

Comment: Can you please give your exact error here ?

Comment: "Must supply api_key"  - full error description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking [here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/android_image_and_video_upload) in the documentation. In the example you need to pass `SignatureProvider`

Example Code:

```
Map config = new HashMap();
config.put("cloud_name", "myCloudName");
MediaManager.init(this, new SignatureProvider(){
  @Override
  public Signature provideSignature(Map options) {
    // replace the following with a function that calls your backend signature generation endpoint
    SignResult res = signUpload(options);  // example name of a function that implements a synchronous HTTPS call
    return new Signature(res.getSignature(), res.getApiKey(), res.getTimestamp());
  }
  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "SampleSignatureProvider"; // for logging purposes
  }
}, config);
```

> To enable signed uploads you need to update your call to the
>   MediaManager's init method with the name of an instance of your class
>   (init(Context, SignatureProvider, Map)). Your class will be
>   implemented whenever an upload must be signed.

See the [SignatureProvider](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_android/blob/524b33f133b2c4c7b05b1664db586405e5c4176b/lib/src/main/java/com/cloudinary/android/signed/SignatureProvider.java) inteface

**EDIT**

For Unsigned upload you haven't mentioned `.unsigned("sample_preset")` with `MediaManager.get().upload(uri)`. For more information [see here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/android_image_and_video_upload#unsigned_upload)

Comment: this is for signed upload, but i am trying unsigned upload.. shouldn't be asking for an api key for an unsigned upload?

Comment: @ghita I have modified my answer. Please check